# Loop for numerating rows between parameters in R

Tags: r

I need to numerate the steps in column `journey` between the rows "session_start". I can't think up how to write a loop for this case.

```
df <- data.table(
  page = c("page_1", "page_2", "page_3", "page_1", "page_2", "page_1", "page_2", "page_3"),
  journey = c("session_start", NA, NA, "session_start", NA, "session_start", NA, NA)      
)
```

The desired result should be like this.

```
df <- data.table(
  page = c("page_1", "page_2", "page_3", "page_1", "page_2", "page_1", "page_2", "page_3"),
  journey = c("session_start", "step_1", "step_2", "session_start", "step_1", "session_start", 
              "step_1", "step_2")

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you want. Be sure to add `stringsAsFactors = F` to the `data.table`, otherwise the `journey` column will not process correctly.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    if (is.na(df$journey[i])) {
        df$journey[i] <- paste('step',step_index,sep='')
        step_index <- step_index + 1
    } else {
        step_index <- 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
df$journey <- ifelse(df$page == "page_1","session_start", gsub(".*_","step_",df$page))
```

Which gives:

```
    > df
     page       journey
1: page_1 session_start
2: page_2        step_2
3: page_3        step_3
4: page_1 session_start
5: page_2        step_2
6: page_1 session_start
7: page_2        step_2
8: page_3        step_3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution with `ave`.

```
i <- df$journey == "session_start"
i[is.na(i)] <- 0L
f <- cumsum(i)
df$journey <- ave(as.character(df$journey), f, FUN = function(s){
  s[is.na(s)] <- paste0("step_", seq_along(s)[-length(s)])
  s
})
```

There might be better ways with package `data.table`, that you are using but I am not fluent in the package.